What are the possible causes of my dog drinking his own urine
This is more of a kudo than a question . Under this topic and the  the final answer edited by DogMumbler.
My husband's 10 year rescue shipperkie, Whisky" drinks his pee, every time inside. He's 10 years old and he's had him years. He use to eat his poop but has stopped since October 2022 when my husband and I married and he relocated from Texas back to Louisiana. We since changed his diet to "The Farmer's Dog and I started taking him outside frequently. That behavior stopped and Whiskey is getting the nutrients needed, he is down to his normal weight for his breed but continues to drink his urine constantly. We have been unsuccessful in training him to hold his urine until potty breaks but no luck there
He has ALL of the symptoms that DogMumbler mentioned. I just thought it was because of possible early environment before I rescued him.
That said, I am taking him to his vet for a alkaline phosphatase test ASAP. Really concerned about possibly of Crushing's disease.
Thanks DogMumbler for bringing this to light.

I've marked this question as duplicate of the question that  DogMumbler so folks who find this question can find your answer. Ideally, we hope people participate in the site, get the reputation needed and upvote posts to show appriciation, rather than post questions to do that.
